# Pickle a django query?

Tags: python, django, pickle

Is it possible to pickle or somehow store a django query in the database? This won`t work :

```
u = User.objects.all 
import cPickle
pickled_query = cPickle.dumps(u) # and store the pickled_query in a db-field.
```

Any thoughts?

Updated:

```
import cPickle

class CustomData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    pickled_query = models.CharField(max_length = 300)

def get_custom_result(self):
    q = cPickle.loads(self.pickled_query)
    return q()

>>> cd = CustomData(name="My data", pickled_query=cPickle.dumps(User.objects.all))
>>> cd.save()
>>> for item in cd.get_custom_result(): print item
# prints all the users in the database, not printing the query result 
# when pickled, but when called like cd.get_custom_result(), that is when 
# the query is actually executed.
```

Now that's what I want to do. I know this actual piece of code won`t run, but it shows my intention; to store a query, not the result, and execute that query at some point in the future.

Update #2:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# adds two users; super and test
>>> u = User.objects.filter(username = 'test')
>>> import cPickle
>>> s = cPickle.dumps(u.query)
>>> s2 = cPickle.loads(s)
>>> o = s2.model.objects.all()
>>> o.query = s2
>>> for i in o: print i
...
super
```

Still not completly satisfied. I know QuerySets are lazy so doing s2.model.objects.all() won't execute a query fetching all users?

Comment: Django can already serialize objects.  It has a serialization module just for this.  Did you read this yet?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/

Comment: Are you trying to pickle the query, or the query results?

Comment: I`m not pickling query result, just the method so I can depickle it later and do : query_method = cpickle.loads(pickled_query); for orm_instance in query_method(): print orm_instance. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: No.  It isn't any clearer.  Please **update** your question with some examples or some use cases or some detailed description of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets) for that. Basically, pickle the `query` attribute if you want to recreate the SQL query, and pickle the whole queryset if you want to pickle a snapshot of the current results.

Your example would do the latter, if you pickled the result of `all()` instead of the bound method.

Comment: Ah! I see, but won't all() execute the query? And I need to know what model the query is related to?

Comment: Query has a `model` attribute. If you pickle the QuerySet (instead of the Query) the current result set is serialized – and that requires it to be executed. Btw: all() does not execute the query.

Comment: @Weholt: no, `all()` does not execute the query. Only when you actually try to iterate the results, it'll be executed.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Calling qs.count() before and after I set the query attribute with my custom query returns the same number.