# Pickle database independent query in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

First of all, I know that my question duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715479/pickle-a-django-query) question. But I supose it's not the same.

I need to save user "search filter". As I understand Django ORM create specific SQL query for different DB. So if I save SQL query I can't migrate on other database with different SQL syntax. 
**Am I wrong?** **If no, how can I save Django side of query, without accsesing to DB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you can suggest better sulution I open for conversation

So... Pickle the function `.filter()` is not the best idea so as saving SQL string for specific DB. I think the best solution for this problem is saving search parameters. In my case it's GET string. I get it:

```
request.META["QUERY_STRING"]
```

And save to DB.

If I need to get it, i just parse:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
QueryDict(request.META["QUERY_STRING"])
```

Aditionally I use **different** form for validate this values (optional) `SearchTrustedForm()`, because if data structure has changed I can save backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you're correct -- mostly. If the SQL dialect that Django compiled the query for isn't compatible with a different backend, it wouldn't work or might work unpredictably.

To save the Django side of the query, why not just save the actual `filter()` statement that you're using or a representation of it that you can convert back on the fly?

Edit: Okay in that case I think you're on the right track based on comments and above answer. If you're parsing a query string already save that in the database as a `CharField` and then just use it to build a Django QuerySet when you retrieve it. If I'm understanding.

Comment: For example if i do something like this: 
`a = Genre.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 10, 20, 8, 9])
 b = pickle.dumps(a)
`, pickle serialize result of filter function. So I do not understand what you mean says: *why not just save the actual filter() statement*.

Comment: So are you wanting to save the *results* or the *statement*? I thought you wanted the statement, but now it sounds like you want to save the results of the QuerySet.

Comment: no no, I just wanted to say that serealizing of filter with parameters return the *result*. I need **statement**

P.S. Sorry I can't insert you name. I don't know why.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin No worries. I've update my answer to reflect what I understand of the problem now.

Comment: Yes you are correct. So now it's my best idea, may be it could be better.